# Need to find specified string next word in each array index

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] =>
Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
[1] =>
Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
[2] =>
Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
[3] =>
Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
[4] =>
___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
[5] =>
Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
)
```

Need to find `___1nam` in array index and get next word `(Mr Muruganandam)`. and push into a new array.

Tried in different ways no luck

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Tried in different ways no luck*, please show them or at least one.

Comment: @Larence cherone i just converted to json and and tried to get and used preg_grep even tried with string functions

Comment: "Mr Muruganandam" isn't the next word, it's the next _two_ words. The next word is simply "Mr".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes

Comment: You still need to show us what you've tried, though. We can help you with your existing code, but we're not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: $string = '___ph';
foreach ($data as $name) {
   
    if (strpos($string, $name) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: $string = '___ph';
foreach ($data as $name) {
  
    if (strpos($string, $name) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: $jsondata = json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 
 
 //$data = str_replace(str_replace('Caller Name:',$data ));
 for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++ ){
  print_r(in_array('___1nam',$data[$i]));exit;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should build your array properly in the first place as you expect to use it.

Though as it looks generally uniform you could switch out your separators (of sorts) with parsable versions, and then use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), in a loop pass by reference to update the original.

```
<?php
$data = [
    'Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com', 
    'Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com', 
    'Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com', 
    'Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com', 
    '___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com', 
    'Enquiry for *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)* User Muruganandam enquired for your business related category at Justdial Feedback Details ___1nam Mr Muruganandam Caller Requirement: Domestic Air Ticketing Agents Call Date & Time: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31 ___ph +919080842161 ___1em nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com'
];

foreach ($data as &$value) {
    // escape &'s
    $value = str_replace('&', '%26', $value);

    // replace separators with parsable keys (*verbose as you could use an array)
    $value = str_replace('Enquiry for ', 'enquiry=', $value);
    $value = str_replace(' User ', '&user=', $value);
    $value = str_replace(' enquired for ', '&subject=', $value);
    $value = str_replace('Feedback Details ___1nam', '___1nam', $value);
    $value = str_replace('___1nam', '&details[name]=', $value);
    $value = str_replace('Caller Requirement: ', '&details[caller]=', $value);
    $value = str_replace(' Agents Call Date %26 Time: ', '&details[date]=', $value);
    $value = str_replace(' ___ph ', '&details[phone]=', $value);
    $value = str_replace(' ___1em ', '&details[email]=', $value);

    parse_str($value, $value);
}

print_r($data);
```

Then you can just access it like `$data[0]['details']['name']`.

https://3v4l.org/iYoWS

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [enquiry] => *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)*
            [user] => Muruganandam
            [subject] => your business related category at Justdial 
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [enquiry] => *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)*
            [user] => Muruganandam
            [subject] => your business related category at Justdial 
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [enquiry] => *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)*
            [user] => Muruganandam
            [subject] => your business related category at Justdial 
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [enquiry] => *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)*
            [user] => Muruganandam
            [subject] => your business related category at Justdial 
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [enquiry] => *S R Air Ticketing & Money Exchange (T Nagar, Chennai)*
            [user] => Muruganandam
            [subject] => your business related category at Justdial 
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Mr Muruganandam 
                    [caller] => Domestic Air Ticketing
                    [date] => Thu, 26 Apr 2018 13:54:31
                    [phone] =>  919080842161
                    [email] => nmsmurugan2000@gmail.com
                )

        )

)
```